# The matrix element of a normal-ordered operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, many-body

Eq (1.137) in Negele and Orland gives the following identity for a normal-ordered operator $A(a_i^\dagger,a_i)$:

$$\langle \phi|A(a_i^\dagger,a_i)|\phi'\rangle=A(\phi_i^*,\phi'_i)e^{\sum \phi_i^*\phi'_i}$$

For the coherent (boson) states $|\phi\rangle=e^{\sum\phi_ia^\dagger_i}|0\rangle $. When I try to prove this I get a factor of 1/2 in the exponent. I'm going to take a simple example $A=a_i^\dagger a_i$ to try and find my mistake. First I define $\eta'=\sum \phi'_ia_i^\dagger$, and use the identity

$$a_i\eta'^n=n\phi'_i\eta'^{n-1}+\eta'^n a_i.$$

Then I can show

$$a_i|\phi'\rangle=(e^{\eta'}a_i+\phi'_ie^{\eta'})|0\rangle$$

One term of which kills the vacuum so I have shown

$$\langle \phi |a^\dagger_i a_i|\phi'\rangle=\langle 0| \phi^*_i\phi'_ie^{\eta^*}e^{\eta'}|0\rangle$$

Then I want to use the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorf formula. The commutator

\begin{equation}
[\eta^*,\eta']=[\sum\phi^*_ia_i,\sum\phi_ja^\dagger_j]=\sum[\phi^*_ia_i,\phi_i'a_i^\dagger]+\sum_{i\neq j}[\phi^*_ia_i,\phi_ja^\dagger_j]=\sum\phi_i^*\phi'_i,\qquad (1)
\end{equation}
and when you commute everything through the second term and kill the vacuum. Since this is a scalar, the BCH formula gives

$$\ln(e^{\eta^*}e^{\eta'})=\eta^*+\eta'+\frac{1}{2}\sum\phi_i^*\phi_i'$$

Rearrange the sum, exponentiate, kill some more vacuum and I get the right expression but with a factor of 1/2!

What am I doing wrong? My first guess is in equation (1), maybe there is some dobule-counting I don't see but you can write things like

$$[\sum,\sum]=[1,\sum]+[2,\sum]+...=[1,1]+[1,\sum_{\neq 1}]+[2,2]+[2,\sum_{\neq 2}]+...$$
$$=\sum[i,i]+\sum_{i\neq j}[i,j].$$

Answer (score 3):

I) OP's factor $\frac{1}{2}$ comes from using the truncated version

$$\tag{1} e^Ae^B~=~e^{A+B+\frac{1}{2}[A,B]}$$

of the [Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula). Formula (1) holds if the commutator $[A,B]$ commutes with both the operators $A$ and $B$.

II) What is actually needed in OP's calculation is rather this version

$$\tag{2} e^Ae^B~=~e^{[A,B]}e^Be^A$$

of the truncated Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula. Formula (2) contains no half. It can easily be derived by using formula (1) twice.

III) Concretely, with $\hbar=1$, the operators $A=\phi^{*}_i a_i$ and $B=\phi^{\prime}_i a^{\dagger}_i$ play the role of annihilation and creation parts, respectively. The commutator $[A,B]~=~\phi^{*}_i\phi^{\prime}_i {\bf 1}$ is a $c$-number. The normal ordered expression (which is needed in OP's calculation) is the rhs. of eq. (2) (as opposed to the rhs. of eq. (1), which is *not* normal ordered). In particular, the bracket of two coherent states reads $\langle\phi |\phi^{\prime} \rangle=e^{\phi^{*}_i\phi^{\prime}_i}$.

Comment: But the commutator $[A,B]=[a,a^\dagger]=1$, a scalar here (I guess a scalar times the identity operator), and that DOES commute with $a$ and $a^\dagger$. I started with the full version of BCH, removed the higher terms that vanish (I think) and used the exponential map to get the thing I wanted. No?

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: I have to say, I am still surprised by this. How can you tell that (2) is normal-ordered if $A$ and $B$ are any old operators whose commutator is proportional to the identity? I see how you can't tell if (1) is normal-ordered, but how can you tell that (2) is?